# How long after bottling will the effects of oxygenation become apparent?

Tags: bottles, oxygenation, bottle, caps

I think it is well understood in the brewing community that oxygen absorbing caps exist and are readily available.  I don't keep any on-hand since my brews tend to be consumed rather quickly and are rarely in the ABV range best suited for aging.  After what length of time in the bottle do the effects of oxygenation become apparent?

Does this differ based on factors such as IBU, ABV, and storage temperature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very much temperature dependent. In an episode of [brewstrong](http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/shows/475), Charlie Bamforth mentions that the rate of oxidization is proportional to temperature, and increases 3 fold for each temperature increase of 10°C/18°F.

So, if your beer is stored at 4°C (39°F), it will oxidize 9 times slower than if it's stored at 24°C (75°F). Loosely speaking, if it takes 9 months to oxidize in the fridge, it would take just 1 month in a warm room.

Racking also introduces a lot of oxygen, unless you do a closed transfer with CO2, so it's best to store the beer cold if you think it will still be around for more than a few weeks.